# Inserting amazon affiliate link in Wordpress by <iframe>

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, iframe

I am trying to inserting my amazon affiliate link on my wordpress website. But it doesn't work. When I publish the site, I can't see it.

Is it possible to insert the affiliate link into wordpress without using a plugin? I am actually using the free version of wp right now, so I can't install any plugins.

Thanks in advance,

Greetings,

Blacktiger800

Comment: When you say Free WordPress, do you mean a Free wordpress.com plan or the self hosted wordpress.org one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can add in html code to a widget, you should be able to add the link. I've done this many times in both WordPress and Drupal and as long as you enter the link in html it always works.

As long as your theme has a widget area, add a text widget here, and place it where you want your link(s) to appear. If you can get a banner link that would probably give you better click rates, so here's how you can add that:

```
<a href="www.youraffiliatelink.com" target="_blank"><img src="www.whereamizonhastheimage.com" alt="Product Name or Description" /></a>
```

The text inside the "alt" area is there as a backup, in case the image fails to load, so you still at least will have a text link. also helps for people using screen readers who can't see images, making your site more accessible, for minimal effort.

If you just want a text link, you can ignore the img tag and go straight to the name of the product or whatever text you want to appear there between the opening and closing of the a tag like this:

```
<a href="www.youraffiliatelink.com" target="_blank"><Your Text Here</a>
```

The target="_blank" part just tells the browser to open a new window/tab, meaning people won't leave your site when clicking on an affiliate link. I typically do this on all links leaving a website I'm developing.